# Unit of "cN.m" used on torque wrench

Tags: experimental-physics, tools, unit

I'm using a torque wrench whose unit is `cN.m`. I wonder what unit this is, and how to convert `N.m` (Newton meter) to `cN.m`.

Comment: I've seen hPa (100 Pa) a number of times in datasheets as an alternate way to say 1mbar pressure, which is a common unit. (1bar = 10^5 Pa).

Comment: @PeteW Over here in SI-land (continental Europe) hectopascals are the only unit ever used to express atmospheric pressure, so everyone is familiar with them from weather forecasts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`100 cN.m`** are  **`1 N.m`**

The **c** before the `N.m` is pronounced *centi*. It's a standard [SI prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix).

1 c of a unit is $\frac{1}{100}$ of a unit.

Therefore to **convert to`N.m`** you need to multiply `cN.m`  with **0.01**.
$$0.01 \text{N.m} = 1 \text{cN.m} =1 \text{N.cm} $$

Probably the prefix **centi** is most commonly encounter used in *centimeter* `cm`.

Regarding the uses of **`cN.m`** or equally **`N.cm`** (which might be more convenient for some people), probably the most common usage (at least that I've personally noticed in recent times) in engineering would be as measuring units of the torque of stepper motors like NEMA 17. These motors are commonly used in 3d printers  (e.g. have a look at this [RepRap link](https://reprap.org/wiki/NEMA_17_Stepper_motor)) and other 'hobbyist' (or more professional) projects.

Comment: Only biologists and medics seem to use centimeters as a standard unit of length in the UK. Engineers invariably use meters or millimeters.

Comment: @alephzero you are 100% right that mechanical/electircal  engineers invariably use mm, however at least where I am from centimeter is a much more commonly used in a daily basis, eg height of a person. Also, - again at least where I am from - civil engineers tent  to use in diagrams cm.

Comment: Are centinewtons actually units people that are lucky enough to not deal with the imperial system use?

Comment: An easier way to think about it is Newton times centimeter.

Comment: Shouldn't this say "Therefore to convert in N.m you need to multiply cN.m by **100**."?

Comment: No, because when you are convert in **m** you need to multiply **cm** by **0.01**. So 100cm multiplied by 0.01 is 1 meter. (at least that's what I meant to convey, but english is not my native language).

Comment: To be precise, in order to convert *a number of* $\mathrm{cN} \cdot \mathrm{m}$ to *a number of* $\mathrm{N} \cdot \mathrm{m}$, you multiply by 0.01. On the other hand, in order to go from the quantity $1\ \mathrm{cN} \cdot \mathrm{m}$ to the quantity $1\ \mathrm{N} \cdot \mathrm{m}$, you multiply by 100. (By the way, "convert in" should be "convert to" or "convert into." The phrase "convert in" is not standard English, and I think most English speakers won't know what "convert in" is supposed to mean until they figure it out from context.)

Comment: @TannerSwett apart from   the correct use of english (which you are correct- I'll correct it in the morning) is there a difference to what I'm writing?

Comment: Nope, you wrote it correctly (aside from the word "in"). I'm just pointing out that when you say "multiply cN.m with 0.01," it's not immediately obvious whether "cN.m" means "the number of cN.m" or "the quantity '1 cN.m.'" That's probably what prompted IMSoP's question.

Answer (score 1):

**cN.m** = **N.cm** = 0.01 N.m

N.cm is more intuitive than cN.m.

'c' is a standard SI prefix indication one-hundredth as in centimeter, 0.01 m.